# R - regex, grep prints out everything

Tags: r, regex

I have this:

```
"81 Delaware St, Staten Island, NY 10304, USA"
```

I want to capture `81 Delaware St,`

Running

```
grep("^.+?,", "81 Delaware St, Staten Island, NY 10304, USA", value= TRUE)
```

Returns:

```
81 Delaware St, Staten Island, NY 10304, USA
```

I tried `perl=TRUE` no help, still everything gets printed out.

Example: [RegEx](http://regexr.com/3erlh), so I know the expression is not wrong.

Comment: Whar do you want to achieve by the regex?

Comment: What are you trying to capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused with the result as your regex actually matches the string you pass to `grep` and `grep` just returns all character vectors that where it finds a match. `grep` does not return *substrings*.

You may use a `sub` with a `,.*` regex that will match a `,` and all chars after it and remove that part leaving just the required substring:

```
s <- "81 Delaware St, Staten Island, NY 10304, USA"
sub(",.*", "", s)
## => [1] "81 Delaware St"
```

See [R demo](http://ideone.com/U0VG1w)

Alternative way is to *match* the substring up to the first `,`:

```
unlist(regmatches(s, gregexpr("^[^,]+", s)))
```

See [this R demo](http://ideone.com/u4hc7l).

Comment: Doesn't it help you achieve what you need?

Comment: Sorry a bit late, yes this makes sense, I didn't really know exactly how grep worked.

Answer (score 0):

> ...so I know the expression is not wrong.

The expression is wrong. The `^.+?` tells grep to return every character from beginning to end.

Here are some helpful resources beyond the R documentation.

[Regular Expressions with The R Language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

[R Regular Expression](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/grep.php)

[Getting and Cleaning Data](http://sux13.github.io/DataScienceSpCourseNotes/3_GETDATA/Getting_and_Cleaning_Data_Course_Notes.html#regular-expressions)

One hint: if your street addresses always contain a comma followed by a space (, ) before listing the street - you can use that to split the addresses from the cities. But there is always a way to extract data.

Comment: *The `^.+?` tells grep to return every character from beginning to end.* is a wrong explanation, and besides, OP regex is different.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the regex being different. Regarding the pattern; regardless of OP's method that pattern will not return the segment of the string being sought.

Comment: The regex selects what I want, but its just that I am using grep all wrong.